# One section "location" isn't completely working, whereas the others are

Tags: linux, nginx

Trying to setup nginx to serve static assets of my web app, I've come up with this, which is partially working:

```
# error!!!!
# always 404: not found
location ~ ^/my_uploads/(images|pdfs|videos)/ {

        # "/opt/my_app123/assets/my_real/uploads_folder/" is the physical path to my uploaded assets

        root /opt/my_app123/assets/my_real/uploads_folder;
```

autoindex off;
    }

```
# below everything working good

location ~ ^/(images|css|js|fonts|videos)/ {
        root /opt/my_app123/assets/static;
        autoindex off;
}

location ~ ^/(favicon.ico|robots.txt) {
        alias /opt/my_app123/assets/static/$1;
}

location = / {
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  [..........]
}
```

All permissions are 777. SELinux isn't even installed. But I keep gettting 404 for anything I'm trying to access in `my_uploads/`

How to fix it?

E.g.

```
my_domain.com/robots.txt # ok

my_domain.com/images/image1.png # ok
my_domain.com/videos/video1.mp4 # ok

my_domain.com/my_uploads/videos/video2.mp4 # not found
my_domain.com/my_uploads/pdfs/my_doc1.pdf # not found
```

Comment: Your `root` is probably wrong. Do you really mean to have `my_uploads` in the path twice?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what do you mean?

Comment: You have configured it to look for a file, e.g. `/opt/my_app123/assets/my_uploads/my_uploads/images/....`

Comment: @MichaelHampton have it? How should I change it? See my update. Why is the root "assets" working properly?

Comment: I don't know how you should change it. It depends on what directory you are actually storing the files. But you never mentioned this anywhere that I can see.

Comment: @MichaelHampton for uploads the physical path--> `/opt/my_app123/assets/my_uploads/{images, pdfs, videos, etc}/{file_name}`

Comment: So if the URL path starts with `/my_uploads/` then the document root should not have it! See the [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/root) for an example.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what should *root* for "/my_uploads/..." look like then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've checked the link but I don't see any mistake in  my config. I've changed it to reflect my real config settings a bit more

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> for uploads the physical path-->
>   /opt/my_app123/assets/my_uploads/{images, pdfs, videos,
>   etc}/{file_name}

For the URI `/my_uploads/videos/video2.mp4`, if the physical file is located in `/opt/my_app123/assets/my_uploads/videos/video2.mp4`, the *document root* is `/opt/my_app123/assets`.

The physical path is calculated by concatenating the value of `root` and the URI.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/my_uploads/(images|pdfs|videos)/ {
    root /opt/my_app123/assets; 
    autoindex off; 
}
```

See [this document](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.